# TYPO3 TCA execute hook after delete in backend

Tags: php, typo3, hook, typo3-extensions, typo3-10.x

I want to manipulate some values and execute a custom function if an object is deleted trought the backend.

ext_localconf.php

```
$GLOBALS ['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['t3lib/class.t3lib_tcemain.php']['processDatamapClass'][''] = TES\TesTest\Hooks\TCEmainHook::class;
$GLOBALS ['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['t3lib/class.t3lib_tcemain.php']['processCmdmapClass'][''] = TES\TesTest\Hooks\TCEmainHook::class;
```

Additionally, I created the following class in my extension /Classes/Hooks/TCEmainHook.php

```
namespace TES\TesTest\Hooks;

use TYPO3\CMS\Core\DataHandling\DataHandler;

class TCEmainHook
{
    public function processCmdmap_deleteAction($table, $id, array $recordToDelete, &$recordWasDeleted, DataHandler $dataHandler)
    {
        var_dump($table);
        var_dump($id);
        die;
    }
}
```

I don't get what I am doing wrong. Does someone have any suggestions?

Comment: Avoid using [''], just use []. For your delete action you do not need the processDatamapClass hook registration. You can also look into the Configuration module (available with lowlevel extension installed) to list all hook implementations available. There should be your visible.